# Is it safe to use “PushFit” fitting on gas pipes?

Tags: safety, pushfit, dangerous, gas

There are many makes of pushfit pipe fittings that make it a lot easer to join pipes, incluing copper pipes, e,g:

- [John Guest Speedfit](http://www.johnguest.com/makeconnect.asp)
- [Cuprofit®- copper push fit](http://www.ibpconex.co.uk/viewRange.php?id=9)
- [Hepworth-HEP20](http://www.hep2o.co.uk/)

Are they safe to use on gas?

Comment: **N** **O** **!!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the UK, it's **not legal** (quite correctly, in my view) for householders to work on gas pipework or fittings **at all**.

If a buildings inspector or surveyor spots pushfit fittings on gas you can expect plenty of trouble down the line... to say nothing of the risk of a pinhole leak or if there's another fire nearby that melts the fitting.

While you might save a few pounds in the short term, do you want to risk your life and that of those around you? A leaky joint in a water pipe might wreck a ceiling or a floor, the same in a gas pipe might kill you.

Head [here](http://www.trustcorgi.com/Pages/default.aspx) for details of the Gas Safety scheme which holds a register of tradespeople who can do the work for you.

Answer (score 3):

The reason copper gas pipes are soldered with silver solder is the melting temperature is much higher. This is done in case your house catches on fire, normal solder would melt and you would have a blow-torch helping burn down your house.

Comment: I have never hard of silver solder being used on gas pipes, are you talking about the US?

Comment: I meant to say brazing.. my grandfather always referred to it as silver soldering.